# How to speed up AR query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let's have a look at the following code:

```
users = []

User.find_each do |u|
 author = u.articles.where('some where statement').limit(1).try(:author)
 users << { user: u.name, author: author }
end

users
```

The problem is when I iterate on each User and Active Record make a call to DB.

I've tried `includes` for `articles` but it only loads all `articles` and then make a `select` from DB, because of `where, limit and author`.

Any ideas how can I avoid to many calls to DB, may be somehow  preload `articles` with whole conditions?

Comment: What's your end goal with this? Collect authors of articles which match your condition?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i've edited the code.The goal is to create new array with User.name and Author. Please, look at updated code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you want one article per user. So, `group by` naturally comes to mind. Something along these lines should work:

```
articles = Article.includes(:user, :author).where(your_where_condition).group(:user_id)
users = articles.map{|a| { user: a.user.name, author: a.author }}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick setup would be:

```
User.includes(articles: :author).joins(:articles).merge(Article.where('some where statement')).map do |u|
  { user: u.name, author: u.articles.first.author }
end
```

But its useless to load all articles to only take one, so you could define a dedicated relationship if `'some where statement'` is fixed.